# gef/peda/pwngdb/pwndbg heap commands not working while using the gdbserver with android phone

Tags: gdb, gdbserver, pwntools

No matter using gef, pwndbg or pwngdb or peda; While runing those commands in android phone with gdbserver, never get the heap command work ? Is there anything with libc.so ? Should I install libc.so debug version in android ? I don't know how to install the debug version of libc.so in android phone ?
Anyone know how to solve this problem

```
gef➤  heap arenas
gef➤  heapinfo
Can not get libc version
Cannot get main_arena's symbol address. Make sure you install libc debug file (libc6-dbg & libc6-dbg:i386 for debian package).
Can't find heap info
gef➤  heapbase
Python Exception <class 'FileNotFoundError'>: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/12607/maps'
Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'>: Error occurred in Python: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/12607/maps'
Error occurred in Python: Error occurred in Python: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/12607/maps'
gef➤  parseheap
Can not get libc version
Cannot get main_arena's symbol address. Make sure you install libc debug file (libc6-dbg & libc6-dbg:i386 for debian package).
can't find heap info
gef➤  heap
[!] Syntax
heap (chunk|chunks|bins|arenas|set-arena)
gef➤  heap chunks
[!] Invalid arena
gef➤
```

How to get the heap/bin commands working correctly with remote target: 8888; Andorid; Is there anything with libc.so ? Should I install libc.so debug version in android ? I don't know how to install the debug version of libc.so in android phone ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.